# Выводит не все элементы из xml

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Мне нужно из xml КПТ Росреестра вывести в одну колонку все кадастровые номера у которых имеются координаты, вторя и третья колонки это сами координаты (x и y). Дальше код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def ordinates(ordinates):
    ordinate_list = []
    for x in ordinates:
        cad_number = [s.find('cad_number').text for s in x.find_all('common_data')
        # for ordinate in x.find_all('ordinate'):
        xx = [cad.text for cad in x.find_all('x')]
        yy = [cad.text for cad in x.find_all('y')]
        ordinate_list.extend([(d,f,a) for d,f,a in zip(cad_number,xx,yy)])
    
    return ordinate_list

for path in Path(file_path).rglob('*.XML'):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as parse:
        xml = parse.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, features="lxml")
        ordinate = ordinates(soup.find_all('base_data'))
        for k in ordinate:
            data = {'Кадастровый номер':k[0],
                    'Координаты по X': k[2],
                    'Координаты по Y': k[2]}
```

---

Выводит следующую информацию (1 кадастровый номер и по одной координате x и y, хотя у кадастрового номера этих координат может быть, для примера, 9 шт.)
Дальше следующий вариант кода:

```
def ordinates(ordinates):
    ordinate_list = []
    value_list_1 = []
    for x in ordinates:
        cad_number = ([s.find('cad_number').text for s in x.find_all('common_data')])
        value_list = ([s.find('value').text for s in x.find_all('common_data')])
        value_list_1.extend([(v,b) for v,b in zip(cad_number,value_list)])
        for ordinate in x.find_all('ordinate'):
            xx = [cad.text for cad in ordinate.find_all('x')]
            yy = [cad.text for cad in ordinate.find_all('y')]
            ordinate_list.extend([(d,f) for d,f in zip(xx,yy)])
     
    return ordinate_list

for path in Path(file_path).rglob('*.XML'):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as parse:
        xml = parse.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, features="lxml")
        ordinate = ordinates(soup.find_all('base_data'))
        for k in ordinate:
            data = {'Кадастровый номер':k[0],
                    'Вид объекта':k[1]}
```

---

Тут функция def ordinates выводит все координаты (если поставить return ordinate_list) либо все кадастровые номера (если поставить return value_list_1), а как вывести все одновременно и записать в:

```
data = {'Кадастровый номер':k[0],
        'Координаты по X': k[2],
        'Координаты по Y': k[2]}
```

[Ссылка](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/RDevGkUBYbj74w) на КПТ в формате xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось переписать еще раз, аккуратно... получилось что хотел)) вот код:

```
for path in Path(file_path).rglob('*.XML'):
    with open(path, 'r',encoding='utf-8-sig') as parse: 
        xml = parse.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, features="xml")
        child_ZY = soup.find_all('land_record')
        data_excel = []
        for value in child_ZY:
            if value.select_one('contours_location x') is not None:
                cad_n = (value.select_one('common_data cad_number').text)
                x = [cad.text for cad in value.find_all('x')]
                y = [cad.text for cad in value.find_all('y')]
                pairs = list(zip(x, y))
                coords = [{"Кадастровый номер": cad_n, "Координаты x": pair[0], "Координаты y": pair[1]} for pair in pairs]
                data_excel.extend(coords)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_excel)
        columns = ["Кадастровый номер", "Координаты x", "Координаты y"]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_excel, columns=columns)
        df.to_excel(excel_file, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

def ordinates(ordinates):
    ordinate_list = []
    for x in ordinates:
        cad_number = [s.find('cad_number').text for s in x.find_all('common_data')]
        for ordinate in x.find_all('ordinate'):
            xx = [cad.text for cad in ordinate.find_all('x')]
            yy = [cad.text for cad in ordinate.find_all('y')]
            ordinate_list.extend([(d,f,a) for d,f,a in zip(cad_number,xx,yy)])
    return ordinate_list

data_list = []
for path in Path(file_path).rglob('*.XML'):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as parse:
        xml = parse.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, features="lxml")
        ordinate = ordinates(soup.find_all('base_data'))
        for k in ordinate:
            data = {'Кадастровый номер':k[0],
                    'Координаты по X': k[1],
                    'Координаты по Y': k[2]}
            data_list.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но заполняет столбец "Кадастровые номера" одним и тем же номером 52:18:0040150:10, а их там больше - 78 вроде (кадастровых номеров с координатами), сделал [скрин](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/AKhgTSkcqI_SHw)